# How hot can soil get if daily temperatures persist above 100°F?

Tags: soil, germination, seedlings, temperature, pines

I am doing some research on ponderosa pines and climate change.  I am currently trying to find (with no luck) how hot soil can get if subjected to direct daily sunlight with temperatures exceeding 100°F.  I am looking into seedling mortality and threshold temperatures.

Comment: If you want to know the actual temperature instead of a computer simulation; bury thermocouples or appropriate thermometers to the desired depth. I have very accurate electronic thermometers with a 5 inch probe/shaft which should easily do the job near the surface.

Comment: What soil type is it, if it's a specific kind?